# ScriptIntrinsicResize and ScriptIntrinsicHistogram not available in Renderscript v8 support library

Tags: android, renderscript

According to the post [Android Support Library 22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) in Android Developer Blog, in the RenderScript section, it is said that [ScriptIntrinsicHistogram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicHistogram.html) and [ScriptIntrinsicResize](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v8/renderscript/ScriptIntrinsicResize.html) are added to the support library. However, I could not find the corresponding classes in the imported library of renderscript-v8.jar. If they are not inside jar library, where are they located and how to use them?

I've the latest version of Android Support Library (Rev. 22.2.1) and SDK Built-tool (22.0.1) installed. As I'm using Eclipse IDE I've also added the following lines in project.properties:

```
renderscript.target=22
renderscript.support.mode=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had the same problem, the solution was to use sufficiently new build tools, e.g. by setting

```
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

in your build.gradle file.